# ValueError: could not convert string to float---how to convert a list of lists of strings into a numpy array type float?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, numpy, floating-point

It looks like I have a malformed numpy array in Python3.x---this was saved as a list of lists of strings.

```
foo = [[7.0352220e-01 5.3130367e-06 1.5167372e-05 1.0797821e-06]
  [1.3130367e-06 2.4584832e-01 2.2375602e-05 7.3299240e-06] [7.2646574e-06 7.1252006e-06 3.0184277e-01 ... 1.0048618e-05 3.1828706e-06 1.0196264e-06]..]
```

I get the following error trying to read in this data as `np.float32` into a numpy array:

```
np.asarray(foo, dtype=np.float32)
```

error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:[[7.0352220e-01 5.3130367e-06 1.5167372e-05 1.0797821e-06][1.3130367e-06 2.4584832e-01 2.2375602e-05 7.3299240e-06] [7.2646574e-06 7.1252006e-06 3.0184277e-01 ... 1.0048618e-05 3.1828706e-06 1.0196264e-06]..]
```

I've tried explicitly converting each list element into a float as follows:

```
try2 = np.asarray(map(np.float32, foo))
```

but it snags on a bracket:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: [
```

What is the recommended way to convert a list of lists of strings into a numpy array, type float?

Comment: Before map, use split for each element.

Comment: What is `foo` really?  The error indicates that it is one string.  If it really was a nested list of strings, and the strings, individually, were valid float representations, your `asarray` would work fine.  The problem is that it isn't even a valid string representation of lists - it's missing the commas that `JSON` needs.  And as you note, the`[]` messes up the simple attempt to `split`.  There's not one way of fixing this.  You could edit the string in various ways to make it parseable  - insert commas, remove [], etc.

Comment: Another thing - see those '...'.  That's missing data.  This looks like a string representation of an numpy array.  You can't recover that array from this string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace the spaces with commas, you can use `json.loads` to read the string as a list, and pass that to `np.asarray`:

```
import json
import numpy as np

foo = "[[7.0352220e-01 5.3130367e-06 1.5167372e-05 1.0797821e-06] \
[1.3130367e-06 2.4584832e-01 2.2375602e-05 7.3299240e-06]]"

a = np.asarray(json.loads(foo.replace(" ", ",")), dtype=np.float32)
print(a)
#array([[7.0352220e-01, 5.3130367e-06, 1.5167372e-05, 1.0797821e-06],
#       [1.3130367e-06, 2.4584832e-01, 2.2375602e-05, 7.3299240e-06]])

print(a.dtype)
#float32
```

This assumes there is exactly 1 space between values. If that is not the case, you can use `re.sub` to replace multiple spaces with a comma:

```
import re
a = np.asarray(json.loads(re.sub("\s+", ",", foo)))
#array([[7.0352221e-01, 5.3130366e-06, 1.5167372e-05, 1.0797821e-06],
#       [1.3130367e-06, 2.4584831e-01, 2.2375601e-05, 7.3299238e-06]],
#      dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have seen, np.asarray() works **only if** dtype has a different datatype from the initial datatype. Please try and remove that argument and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

How is your string data shaped? Probably the simplest way is to use split() and iterate over the list. Example (list of lists of strings) that worked for me:

```
foo = [['7.0352220e-01 5.3130367e-06 1.5167372e-05 1.0797821e-06'],
       ['7.0352220e-01 5.3130367e-06 1.5167372e-05 1.0797821e-06']]
arr = np.array([[value.split() for value in row][0] for row in foo], dtype='<f8')
```

(Note: the [0] is used as split creates a list itself. You can use np.reshape in alternative)

EDIT: if its a string representation (not a list of strings as stated in the OP):

```
foo = '[[7.0352220e-01 5.3130367e-06 1.5167372e-05 1.0797821e-06][7.0352220e-01 5.3130367e-06 1.5167372e-05 1.0797821e-06]'
arr=np.array([line.split() for line in foo.replace('[','').replace(']]','').split(']')], dtype='<f8')
```

Comment: It's not a list of strings, it's a string representation of a list

Comment: I didn't ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
foo = [['7.0352220e-01 5.3130367e-06 1.5167372e-05 1.0797821e-06'],
       ['1.3130367e-06 2.4584832e-01 2.2375602e-05 7.3299240e-06'], 
       ['7.2646574e-06 7.1252006e-06 3.0184277e-01 1.0048618e-05']]
```

Try this to split each string

```
foo = [row[i].split() for row in foo for i in range(len(foo[0]))]
```

This for changing type to floats.

```
foo = [[float(row[i]) for i in range(len(foo[0]))] for row in foo]

print(type(foo[0][1]))

>> float
```

Then turn it into a numpy array:

```
foo = np.array(foo)

print(type(foo[0][1]))

>> numpy.float64
```

Comment: Your answer fits the word description, but not the example or error.